# Change CCSprite images at runtime

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

need to change the `CCSprite` images at runtime, i have to delete the previous loaded images and display new after a specific inter of `NSTimer`, i am using `[imagesContainer removeChildByTag:0 cleanup:YES];` but not working

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: i saw following marked as answer in one similar question but its not working how to implement this

CCTexture2D* tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"new_image_name"];
[spriteWant2Change setTexture: tex];
\

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the sprite like you're doing and add a new sprite but remember to add it to the layer with addChild:

```
 CCSprite *theNewSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"newImage.png"];
 [LayerYouWantToAdd addChild:theNewSprite]
```

Or just change the texture of the sprite.  This works for me.

```
[theSprite setTexture:[[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"newImage.png"]texture]];
```